# OkHttp token interceptor retries forever

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm making an OkHttp interceptor so it retry to sign in when any end point returns a 401 error, but the interceptor is looping forever.

I've also tried to add a counter, but the counter resets itself every time.

Here's my code:

```
object Service {

    private fun getOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(getLoggingInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(NetworkInterceptor())
                .build()
    }

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
                .build()
    }
}

class NetworkInterceptor: Interceptor {
    var counter = 0

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response? {
        val originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request())

        if (!originalResponse.isSuccessful && originalResponse.code() == 401) {
            Log.e("NetworkInterceptor", "Network error 401. Counter = $counter")
            counter++

            val refreshedToken = refreshToken()
            Log.e("NetworkInterceptor", "refreshedToken = $refreshedToken")
        }


        return originalResponse
    }

    private fun refreshToken(): String {
        val context = MyApp.appContext
        val preferencesUtil = SharePreferencesUtils(context)
        val username = preferencesUtil.getUsername()
        val password = preferencesUtil.getPassword()
        val login = AuthService().loginSync(username, password).execute()
        return login.body()?.access_token!!
    }
}
```

I have tried this with an Auth call being an RxJava `Single`, and a regular synchronous `Call<>`

In each case, the call happens forever, the 401 gets returned forever, and the counter always stays at 0.

Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure how the rest work, but shouldn't you add your token to the request somehow? 

        client.addInterceptor { it ->
            val request = it.request()
            val authRequest = request
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", refreshToken())
                    .build()
            return@addInterceptor it.proceed(authRequest)
        }

Comment: I don't think that's needed. My login call is adding that in the header already

Comment: It looks like you are proceeding with the previous request, then you refresh your token (and do nothing with it) and return the failing request. You should get the current request with chain.request(), then add your refreshed token to the request and then call chain.proceed(with your new request)

Comment: Did you actually check if the header is added in the request @TooManyEduardos

Comment: Well I get this loop, even with the original login call. So, if the first username/password combo is invalid, I still end up in a loop.
This is for the case where a token doesn't even exist yet

Comment: Please try the above code I added. Also have a look at adding an Authenticator : https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html

Comment: In the authenticator you can check the previous response and return null if its a 401. Okhttp will then fail and go out of the loop responding with a 401

Comment: Ok, I'll give the authenticator a try. I would rather get my code working though. It should be a simple thing that's resetting the counter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168888/discussion-between-smashing-and-toomanyeduardos).

Answer (score 1):

Add as a NetworkInterceptor using

```
addNetworkInterceptor(NetworkInterceptor)
```

refer to this link for further clarification: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors